# Measuring if LED power is active

Tags: voltage, led, multimeter, motherboard

Apologies for ignorance. I have a computer motherboard with a broken connector to its LED power indicator. Everything else works fine but I would like to get the LED connection up and running. Where the LED connector used to be there are four very small contacts but only two wires emerging from the LED housing. I suspect two of the contacts were originally electrical contacts to the LED and the other two "contacts" may have been structural to hold the (tiny) connector to the board? I think I know which is which but can I use a multimeter in voltage mode to discover which of the four are live? I assume, perhaps wrongly, that if I select the "wrong" pair out of the four then voltage mode is unlikely to cause damage to the rest of the motherboard? Also, why ideas about the likely voltage of these LED inputs? And, since I don't feel confident enough to attempt micro-soldering once I identify the contacts, would it be possible to use a conductive adhesive or are such things garbage?

Comment: Can you take a picture and add it to your question?

Comment: Can you include a photo? Also, keep in mind that repair questions are [off-topic](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), so this may result in closure of your question.

Comment: @JYelton according to the close reason, they are on-topic if the person asking has an understanding of what they are repairing. With this just being an LED, I don't think very much understanding is necessary...

Comment: Digital voltmeters are relatively safe with a high input impedance.  Your highest risk is from ESD, especially when the board is powered up.

Comment: @PerryWebb: Or from accidentally shorting together two contacts (i.e. creating a path through the leads without going through the meter)